# change value src in html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to change the image size or any value in HTML page by this way dropdown list.

this is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

   <select id="selectbox" name="">
              <option value="empty"></option>
              <option value="firstSize">1</option>
              <option value="SecondSize">2</option>
</select>
<br><br>

    <img src="https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=768,432">
</div> 

  </body>
</html>
```

If selecting 1 from selectbox I want to change the size of the image above src to `"https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=400,200"`

Comment: What is the relationship between the option element's value and the desired image dimensions? Do you have a dictionary to look up against?

Comment: I don' have a dictionary. I'm a beginner I just want to know if I can change the src for any object in page

Comment: Yes you can. What you're trying to do can be easily put together by checking out solutions that allows you to listen to change events on the `<select>` element, and then some basic if/else statements to read the `<select>` element's value that will set the image source of the element.

Comment: I find this example code: `https://codepen.io/ScribbleScratch/pen/KqQmqJ?editors=1111`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, you can change the button's text if you want

```js
function check(){
var val = document.getElementById("selectbox").value
var pic =  document.getElementById("img")
if(val==="firstSize"){
pic.setAttribute('src','https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=400,200')
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

   <select id="selectbox" name="">
              <option value="empty"></option>
              <option value="firstSize">1</option>
              <option value="SecondSize">2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
<br><br>
    <img src="https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=768,432" id="img">
</div> 

  </body>
</html>
```

OR
you can do

```js
function check(){
var val = document.getElementById("selectbox").value
var pic =  document.getElementById("img")
if(val==="firstSize"){
pic.setAttribute('src','https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=400,200')
}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

   <select onchange="check()" id="selectbox" name="">
              <option hidden value="empty"></option>
              <option value="firstSize">1</option>
              <option value="SecondSize">2</option>
</select>

<br><br>
    <img src="https://www.ask.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2022/02/PowerOfDogPromo.jpeg?resize=768,432" id="img">
</div> 

  </body>
</html>
```

what's different in snippet 1 and 2 is in number 2 there's no button, when you click an option it will change and you cannot select the empty value

you can combine 1 and 2 using hidden and no button but if it breaks just post in this question/post

Comment: I'd generally advice against using inline JS.

Comment: I'm not using inline js, I'm using the stackoverflow snippets thing

Comment: `onchange="check()"` is inline JS. What I mean is, using `addEventListener` is the recommended way

Comment: oh, I used that so it would be easier to understand and less code

Comment: Thank bro, I use it on another page for a website, but not work, the tree is: `body, div, dive, dive, iframe` the src in iframe tag. how can I get it

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `<div class="w3-white w3-center w3-content" id="howto_padding">
  <div class="codeeditorbr-container" style="text-align:left;">
    <div class="codeeditorbr-row">
      <div class="codeeditorbr-column codeeditorbr-left">
      </div>
      <div class="codeeditorbr-column codeeditorbr-middle">
        <input type="text" disabled="" class="codeeditorbr-input" value="www.w3schools.com/howto/">
      </div>
    </div>
    <iframe src="/howto/tryhow_js_slideshow_ifr.htm" id="howto_iframe"></iframe>
  </div>`

Comment: see comment above how can I get src in `<iframe src="/howto/tryhow_js_slideshow_ifr.htm" id="howto_iframe"></iframe>` to change it. this code in `https://www.w3schools.com/`

Comment: so how to change iframe src?

Comment: change `/howto/tryhow_js_slideshow_ifr.htm` to another url. I do same method above but not working